# onSelectionChange trigger in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, eventtrigger, showmodaldialog

I have a script on Google Sheets that works fine from a menu. The script is designed that when I select a certain cell, then run the script using the menu choice I created, it uses an HTML template to create a form, and the results of that form create content for that cell. I would like to simplify the process and use the 'onSelectionChange' trigger to see if they selected that cell. When I use that trigger to call the script, on the last line of this section:

```
const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('selDialog');
template.optionsData = getPlayers();
const html = template.evaluate();
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select Players');
```

I find the error in the Stackdriver logs `Exception: You do not have permission to call Ui.showModalDialog. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui`

I have searched the error, but I am still unsure how to resolve it. Should I use a different method of displaying the HTML form that I use to collect the data? I have seen the suggestion that perhaps showModalDialog is depreciated. I just find it odd that it works perfectly if I call the script from a custom menu in Sheets rather than using 'onSelectionChange'

Comment: are you sure you want to use `onSelectionChange` ? your script will be executed even if you make other irrelevant selections, switch sheets, or select a full column or whatever.

Comment: Basically, "Simple" triggers can't access htmlservice. So, you can't do that( even though I proposed a twisted workaround in one of the duplicate answers linked, it still can't be used with htmlservice/ui)